# Mistyped URLs sending me to blank pages

Tags: 404, blank-screen

My original EE setup had it where if you mistype a url (eg. www.site.com/carrers) it is set to load in an empty template. Just recently, if you mistype URLs, you get a blank page of nothing.

Any ideas as what's going on and a remedy?

EE 2.6.1

Comment: Check under Design > Templates > Global Preferences and see what template your 404 Page setting is using. Is it the 'blank' template you want it to point to?

Comment: 404 set to none. I have two setups, a staging and a dev. Dev is still working, it looks like all settings are carbon copies.

Comment: For testing try changing it from none to a test template to see if it redirects to that template?

Comment: When I try setting it to a different template, and save. The changes don't take. It still says none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: My template caching system interfered with page generating. My dev environment didn't have the cache working, so it appeard that the templates were working...

Comment: Please mark this as "answered" so it no longer shows in the "unanswered" queue, thanks!